# Get Online Word List

Tags: api, list, words

I need an online resource where I can get list of words using an API with certain configuration, per example, minimum/maximum length of word, the number of words.

Comment: Why you don't want to do this offline?

Comment: Sounds way too specialized to be an existing API, simple to build one on or offline with a word-list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database - or for junk words http://loripsum.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you mean an API providing *English* words. Based on the [SOWPODS](http://www.freescrabbledictionary.com/sowpods.txt) word list I created this [API for my Wordfeud cheat engine](http://api.wordfeuds.com/feed.php?q=pan&position=0&lang=en&min=0&max=15). Usage is based on backlinking to the domain front page. Feel free to use it and comment on functionality.