# Regular Expressions: Finding dictionary words

Tags: regex, api

I'm done with this task, but there seems a problem. I'm working on a Word Scramble game and I need to get online dictionary words. I was able to store the words and their definitions in Lists using this regular expression to find the words: (can't post the link) **"^[a-z]{3}$"**.

However, it is matching words like BSD, DCA, DCC, etc..words that stand for something but not actual words like COW, INN, BOW etc...

I'm obtaining both types but I want to eliminate the former. How could this be done using RE?

Comment: Are you doing a case sensitive match? Perhaps the abbreviations are all upper case and you regex is too.

Comment: This should capture all words between `aaa-zzz`, a regular expression can't distinguish between abbreviations and words? You might want to try `[a-zA-z]` though, as you are now only matching lower case characters.

Comment: @Dualinity actually, the service only provides lower case words, and I know it won't distinguish, all I'm asking for is a regex that matches words and not abbreviations.

Comment: @DavidC it only serves lower case..but the uppercase was an example, results are actually lower case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your goal is to distinguish series of characters which correspond to valid English words?  As Dualinity says, that's not something a regex can do.

You'll need a dictionary, or at least a word list.  This is described elsewhere on SO ([How to get english language word database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database)).  Slurp that file into your language's `Set` object, and test each incoming word against this list.

This will only be an approximation: the free dictionaries out there probably don't have all variants ("exchange", "exchanges", "exchanged") slang, or proper names ("Humphrey").

Comment: so after having to go through parsing XML files, I will go for your suggestion. Word text files are quicker and more reliable.