# Is it possible to get a natural word after it has been stemmed?

Tags: nlp, stemming, porter-stemmer

I have a word ***play*** which after stemming has become ***plai***. Now I want to get ***play*** again. Is it possible? I have used Porter's Stemmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stemmer is able to process artificial non-existing words. Would you like them to be returned as elements of a set of all possible words? How do you know that the word doesn't exist and shouldn't be returned?

As an option: find a dictionary of all words and their forms. Find a stem for every of them. Save this projection as a map: ( stem, list of all word forms ). So you'll be able to get the list of all word forms for a given stem.

**UPD:**
If you need all possible words including non-existing then I can offer such an algorithm (it's not checked, just a suggestion):

[Porter stemming algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/porter/stemmer.html). We need a reversed version.

If the rule in straight algorithm has a form `(m>1) E ->` (delete last E) then the reversed rule would be "fork with E" which means we need to try alternative ways. E.g., in straight algorithm `probate -> probat`, in reversed we have two alternatives: `probat -> { probat, probate }`. Each of these alternatives should be separately processed further. Note that this is a *set* of alternatives, so we will process only distinct words. Such a rule would have the following form: `A -> { , B, C }`, which means "replace ending A in three alternative ways: leave as-is, with B and with C".

```
Step 5b: (m>1) *L -> { , +L } // Add L if there's L at the end.
Step 5a: (m>1) -> { , +E }
         (m=1 and not *o) -> { , +E } // *o is a special condition, it's not *O.
Step 4: (m>1) *S or *T -> { , +ION }
        (m>1) -> { , +AL, +ANCE, +ENCE, ..., +IVE, +IZE }
Step 3: (m>0) *AL -> { , +IZE }
        (m>0) *IC -> { , +ATE, +ITI, +AL }
        (m>0) -> { , +ATIVE, +FUL, +NESS }
Step 2: (m>0) *ATE -> { , ATIONAL } // Replace ATE.
        (m>0) *TION -> { , +AL } // Add AL at the end.
        (m>0) *ENCE -> { , ENCI } // Replace ENCE.
        ...
        (m>0) *BLE -> { , BILITI } // Replace BLE.
Step 1c: (*v*) *I -> { , Y } // Replace I.
Step 1b: (m=1 and *oE) -> { , +D, delete last E and add ING } // *o is a special condition.
         (*v*c and not (*L or *S or *Z)) -> { , add last consonant +ED, add last consonant + ING }
         *IZE -> { , IZING, +D }
         (*v*BLE) -> { , +D, delete last E and add ING }
         *ATE -> { , ATING, +D }
         (*v*) -> { , +ED, +ING }
         (m>0) *EE -> { , +D }
Step 1a: *I -> { , +ES }
         *SS -> { , +ES }
         not *S -> { , +S }
```

The straight algorithm had to choose first longest rule. The reversed algorithm should use all the rules.

Example (straight):

```
Input: PLAYING
Step 1a doesn't match.
PLAYING -> PLAY (Step 1b)
PLAY -> PLAI (Step 1c)
m=0, so the steps 2-5 don't match.
Result: PLAI
```

Reversed:

```
Input: PLAI
m=0, so the steps 2-5 are skipped
Step 1c:
PLAI -> { PLAI, PLAY }
Step 1b:
PLAI -> { PLAI, PLAIED, PLAIING }
PLAY -> { PLAY, PLAYED, PLAYING }
Resulting set: { PLAI, PLAIED, PLAIING, PLAY, PLAYED, PLAYING }
Step 1a:
PLAI -> { PLAI, PLAIS, PLAIES }
PLAIED -> { PLAIED, PLAIEDS }
PLAIING -> { PLAIING, PLAIINGS }
PLAY -> { PLAY, PLAYS }
PLAYED -> { PLAYED, PLAYEDS }
PLAYING -> { PLAYING, PLAYINGS }
Resulting set: { PLAI, PLAIS, PLAIES, PLAIED, PLAIEDS, PLAIING, PLAIINGS, PLAY, PLAYS, PLAYED, PLAYEDS, PLAYING, PLAYINGS }
```

I've checked all those words at [Michael Tontchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28444811/4540645)'s link. The result for every of them is "plai" (note that the site doesn't accept upper-case input).

Comment: thanks for ur answer. where can I get such a dictionary. I am coding in PHP

Comment: @eddard.stark, take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/741003/a-text-file-with-a-list-of-words) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database). You just need a big text file which will be processed once to obtain `( stem, list of words )` pairs for storing them in any local database (or in data structures like Patricia tree or DAWG).

Comment: @eddard.stark, I've updated my answer for the case of all possible (including non-existing) variants.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly not. Many different words, after being stemmed, can become plai: including play and playing.

Try it here: http://9ol.es/porter_js_demo.html

So if, given plai, it could have come from either word, it's not deterministic. Or do you want to get the set of all possible words that stem to plai?

**Update:** Qualtagh mentions some good ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to get a set of possible words that come plai?