# Capitalize each word in string that has no spaces

Tags: c#, asp.net, title-case

I am trying to figure out if there are existing libraries/methods that would allow you to capitalize each word in a string, however the words have no spaces.  For example:

`"blueparrot"` should be converted to `"BlueParrot"`

I know that if there were spaces, I can accomplish this with:

```
var textInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).TextInfo;
textInfo.ToTitleCase("blue parrot");
```

However, without the spacing, the outcome is

> Blueparrot

Comment: This would rather difficult, though, wouldn't it? How would you handle compound words?

Comment: You need a dictionary of every existing word

Comment: I can think of a way where it goes through each letter and starts combining words, where it finds them in a dictionary.  Yes it would not be perfect, but I think possible.  Take the longest words it can combine for example.

Anyhow, I thought I would ask and see if there was a genius out there that figured it out and wrote a method.

Comment: @KennethK. -- I'm thinking more slow than difficult, and certainly there would be ambiguities. If you've got access to a dictionary table and an `IsWord()` method, you can bite off characters one at a time until you've got a word. Wash, rinse and repeat.

Comment: Good luck with a dictionary, and biting off characters until you get a word, when the words is `Totaleclipse` you'll end up with `ToTaleClipSe`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database) may inspire.

Comment: Depending on how you implement it, sure it could be slow. But my understanding of why NLP is so difficult is that a computer cannot decipher the meaning of words and sentences. If I write `In the mean time it takes to read this sentence...`, how does the computer determine whether or not I meant "mean time" or "meantime"? In a true NLP you'd have more information, I believe, but in this question you won't have enough information to make the determination. It'll be a crude manipulation, but the OP seems OK with that.

Comment: @Jamiec - excellent example! Using a [stopword list](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords) might help in those cases.

Comment: @BobKaufman - I note that neither "blue" nor "Parrot" is on that list

Comment: Along the lines of @Jamiec's first comment, words starting with S will often be a problem because it would be hard for the algorithm to know whether the previous word was plural or if the S is part of the next word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy solution to this except to say that *something* puts that string of 2 words together to start with, it is at that point that you need to either provide the information on where the word break is, or format it appropriately.