# How can I check if a string given is a real word?

Tags: vb.net, anagram

I am making a program that solves anagrams in Visual Basic. How can I check if a string given by the anagram solver is a real word? I know I will have to access some sort of dictionary but I have no idea how to do this?

I need a function that checks the word to return a true/false boolean value. Is this possible?

I'm using Visual Basic in Microsoft's VS2015.

Comment: Of course this is possible, but given you haven't said what you've tried so far, or even what format the dictionary will be in, it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: @Carcigenicate So far I've got the code that generates the random string of letters (see below) however I have no idea how dictionaries work in Visual Basic and so that's what I'm also asking for help in. What format would you recommend?

Comment: `Dim lettersgiven() As Char = {"a"c, "b"c, "d"c, "e"c, "f"c}
Dim results As New List(Of String)
For start As Integer = 0 To lettersgiven.Length - 1
Dim usedindices As New List(Of Integer)
For j As Integer = 1 To lettersgiven.Length
Dim i As Integer = start
While usedindices.Contains(i)
                    i = (i + 1) Mod lettersgiven.Length
End While
usedindices.Add(i)
Next
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
For Each i As Integer In usedindices
sb.Append(lettersgiven(i))
Next
If LookupDictionary(sb.ToString()) Then results.Add(sb.ToString())
Next`

Comment: Have you thought of making requests to some free dictionary API's?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2213607/1043824 gives a file with lots of words. You can search through it to check for existance. Searching is tough in flat files. You may want to put it in a database and sql search it. Hitting an api is a neat idea, but i guess it is over the high water mark.

Comment: @gdrt94 thanks for your answer. I'll try that out and get back to you.

Comment: @inquisitive thank you!

Comment: Check http://www.dictionaryapi.com/products/api-collegiate-dictionary.htm

Comment: One solution is to check your word has no spaces first then use one of the myriads of spell checking examples. If it comes back as an error...it is not a real word. However, spell checking is not that easy either for a newb.

Comment: Btw if you are using WPF the spell check part is easy. If you are using windows forms I suggest you create and use a WPF control on your form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hunspell is pretty easy to use.

- Install the .net-library through Nuget (open your project in Visual Studio, then > Extras > Nuget-Package-Manager -> Console, type `Install-Package NHunspell`)
- Download the .aiff and .dic files, see the dictionaries link on the Hunspell project page. Include these files in your project or use absolute paths.

Sample Code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Using h As New NHunspell.Hunspell(
        "...path ...\en_US.aff",
        "...path ...\en_US.dic")
        Me.TextBox1.BackColor = If(h.Spell(Me.TextBox1.Text),
            Color.PaleGreen, Color.PeachPuff)
    End Using
End Sub
```

[Hunspell](http://hunspell.github.io/)

[.net library NHunspell](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NHunspell/)

[NHunspell C# Code Samples](http://www.crawler-lib.net/csharp-code-samples-nhunspell)

Answer (score 1):

If your are using WPF then checking if a word in a textbox can be done simply by checking if it has a spelling error.

```
Public Function WordOk(Word As String) As Boolean
    return TextBox1.GetNextSpellingErrorCharacterIndex(0, Windows.Documents.LogicalDirection.Forward) < 0 
End Function
```

If you are using windows forms then you can create a "User Control (WPF)" to do the same thing, though it is a bit tricky to explain how to do that here.

(There may be a better test than the one I showed though.. I'm not overly familiar with WPF)