# Randomly Generate Meaningful(Valid) English Words In Android Application

Tags: java, android, string, dictionary

I am making a *Dictionary Application*. I am using `Pearson Dictionary API` for the same. I need to generate a word so that I could query that word for its definition.

**PROBLEM**

I know how to generate a *random word* but I don't know how to generate a meaningful English word.

I tried to solve this problem by requesting a JSON response and checking the `results[]`(results[ ]  hold definitions for the word) in the response. So, if `results[].lenght > 0` then the word is a valid English word.

**But the solution above has its own serious problem**: Suppose I want to generate a 5 letter word, there are as many as `26^5 = 11881376`different combinations whereas there aren't as many 5 letter meaningful English words. As the letters in the word increases, the number of combinations increases too. Thus, generating a meaningful word can take a very long time.

**How can I check if the generated word is a meaningful English word or not? Isn't there any feasible programmatic way of doing this?**

**OR Is there any other way I could solve this Problem?**

Comment: You either generate random strings of letters and see if they're words (which, as you realise, is very slow) or you store a list of "known good" words and select randomly from that list. How big that list needs to be depends on what you're trying to achieve.  [According to this page](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language) the OED has 171k main entries, but [according to this page](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/05/vocabulary-size) an average adult knows about 30,000 so a prudent selection of 50,000 should cover most things.

Comment: Wouldn't that increase the size of my app?

Comment: Yes, obviously. But 50,000 x 10 letters (which is almost certainly more than the average) is only about 1/2MB, and there would be ways of compressing that.

Comment: Where can I find such lists???

Comment: For curiosity, I'd just grabbed [one from here](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words) that has 350,000+ words (including variants). This just happened to be the top result from Googling "english word list".

Comment: I will accept your answer(if you write one) if I don't get any better solution. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, you either generate random strings of letters and check to see if they're words (which, as you realise, is very slow, hit-or-miss approach) or you store a list of "known good" words and select randomly from that list.

How big that list needs to be depends on what you're trying to achieve.

According to [this page](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language) the OED has around 171,476 main entries, not including variants like plurals (*cat*, *cats*), standard variants (*sit*, *sitting*), nor words that have multiple classes (e.g. *dog* can be a noun [the animal] or a verb [to follow persistently] etc.). According to [this page](http://www.economist.com/blogs/johnson/2013/05/vocabulary-size) an average adult knows between 20,000 and 35,000 words, so a prudent selection of 50,000 should cover most general purpose uses.

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2213607/2096401) (now closed) provide a number of sources for word-lists. Examining one of them (originally provided by infochimps.org but available as a [simple text-list on github](https://github.com/docdis/english-words)) shows that the average length of 350,000+ words is just under 10 characters.  For Linux (and possibly other flavours) `/usr/share/dict/words` may be a useful place to start.

Answer (score 1):

There is this beautifull text file containing all english wordS:

https://github.com/AlexHakman/Java-challenge/blob/master/words.txt

You can then generate 5 letter words based on whats inside this text document :)

Get per line the length of the line, or just generate and compare it with the text file :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it random because you need to spend time verifying just store a dictionary of the words that you would require and have a lookup table for it.

A relatively complete dictionary for English is about 2MBs compressed like the one here http://wordlist.aspell.net/12dicts/

Even for an Android app unless you're targeting really under powered devices it shouldn't be that big.

You can use SQLite to store the data so it may take up a bit more storage but you get SQL as your query language rather than making up your own.

Since you would also need a bit of randomness, each row can add some sort of randomized key that you can further query.

If you really wanted to limit it to 5 characters then just use a subset of the dictionary.  But this will allow you to have an arbitrary length even length ranges (e.g. 2 to 10 characters)