# I need vocabulary database which classified word

Tags: database

I am looking for a vocabulary database in English which classifies words by grade. For example: beginning words, intermediate words and advanced words list. Do you know any database like that?

Comment: [How to get english language word database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213607/how-to-get-english-language-word-database)

Answer (score 1):

how about text? you can use tiny text, text, long text. varchar or string its still okay